# Where to start with speech synthesis

Tags: speech-synthesis

You guys may be familiar with Google's TTS engine: [here](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=text).

I have a basic understanding of how something like that is able to analyze the input and pick out different syllables/parts of speech, but where would I start if I wanted to create a "voice" for a TTS system?

Answer (score 0):

That's a question that I spent nearly a semester in college learning the answer to, and  a year (or more) of classes beforehand to learn the underlying signal processing required to understand the process. Whole classes are devoted to speech synthesis, and whole curriculums to signal processing.

One can think of the human vocal tract as a filter, and the glottis as an impulse generator—that is, speech is actually the result of an impulse train filtered by the vocal tract, mouth, and nasal cavity.

For every phoneme, the "filter" will be different, so you will need a library of phonemes to generate "filters" for. Theoretically, inverse filtering could be used on a library of phoneme sound clips to find "filter" coefficients. The Levinson-Durbin recursion is often used to find LPC coefficients.

A glottal pulse train must be created. A simple way to do this is to convolve a pulse train with a positive half-sine wave.

Finally, filter the glottal pulse train with the "filter" coefficients associated with the phoneme you wish to create.

But that's only for voiced speech. In order to generate unvoiced speech, a simple solution is to filter a random noise signal with "filter" coefficients associated with unvoiced speech phonemes.

One layer of abstraction above that, create a list of phonemes needed, and concatenate. Simple as pie!

UPDATE:

A friend pointed out Festival, a "black box" to input text and get speech out: http://festvox.org/festival/